# Separating string from multiple columns in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, csv

I have a dataset that looks a bit like this

```
Species   Trend2001   TrendLimits2001   Trend 2002   TrendLimits2002
 Dog        -1.5        -1,-1.64          -1.0         -0.56,-2.0 
 Cat         2.3         2.0,3.1           1.75          1,2.2 
 Mouse       0.65       -0.3,1.0          1.02         -0.1,1.5
```

I want to split the "TrendLimits" columns into two columns called LowerLimits and UpperLimits. I know how to do this for each column separately but is there a way to get R to split all the columns based on the fact that they have "," present? In my actual dataset I have over 100 columns that need to be split and I don't wanna have to write the code out for each one.

What I hope my data looks like at the end is

```
Species   Trend2001    LowerLimits2001   UpperLimits2001  Trend 2002   LowerLimits2002    UpperLimits2002
 Dog        -1.5           -1                -1.64          -1.0         -0.56                -2.0 
 Cat         2.3           2.0                3.1           1.75          1                    2.2 
 Mouse       0.65         -0.3                1.0           1.02         -0.1                  1.5
```

I'm very new to R so please give detailed answers :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `separate` function in the `tidyverse` is also useful for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, c("TrendLimits2001", "TrendLimits2002"), sep=",")
```

---

Or using `base R`, with `read.csv`, create the basename of columns ('v1') and `paste` the year value as suffix with `paste0` and `rep`, then loop over the columns that have 'TrendLimits' as substring in column names, read with `read.csv` bind the `list` of data.frames with `cbind` and update the original dataset by assignment

```
v1 <- c("LowerLimits", "UpperLimits")
nm1 <- paste0(v1, rep(2001:2002, each = length(v1)))
nm2 <- grep("TrendLimits", names(df1), value = TRUE)
df1[nm1] <- do.call(cbind, lapply(df1[nm2], function(x)
     read.csv(text = as.character(x), header = FALSE)))
df1[nm2] <- NULL
df1
#  Species Trend2001 Trend2002 LowerLimits2001 UpperLimits2001 LowerLimits2002 UpperLimits2002
#1     Dog     -1.50     -1.00            -1.0           -1.64           -0.56            -2.0
#2     Cat      2.30      1.75             2.0            3.10            1.00             2.2
#3   Mouse      0.65      1.02            -0.3            1.00           -0.10             1.5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Species = c("Dog", "Cat", "Mouse"), Trend2001 = c(-1.5, 
2.3, 0.65), TrendLimits2001 = c("-1,-1.64", "2.0,3.1", "-0.3,1.0"
), Trend2002 = c(-1, 1.75, 1.02), TrendLimits2002 = c("-0.56,-2.0", 
"1,2.2", "-0.1,1.5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: That still requires me to name the specific column for each. Is there a way that this can be done without naming the columns? I have over 100 columns that I would have to name if I used cSplit

Comment: @CamiHurtado Here, I am assuming that your column names are TrendLimits, so the base R solution is created with that in mind

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I don't want to have to write out the name of each column e.g. c("TrendLimits2001", "TrendLimits2002"...etc) or the new column names e.g. c("LowerLimits2001", "UpperLimits2001",  "LowerLimits2002", 
                "UpperLimits2002"), and the two codes that you wrote as a solution both write them out.

Comment: @CamiHurtado In the second solution, I updated wth `paste` and `rep` (if you have checked it).  Only thing that is speciffied is `v1 <- c("LowerLimits", "UpperLimits")`

Comment: @CamiHurtado I guess you wanted to remove the TrendLimits original column as well, right?